# Changing the values on second <select> tag after changing the first <select>

Tags: php, jquery

The title says my goal here. I'm trying to change the second select tag's values on change of the first tag. Here is what I've tried. The values are coming from the database. So this will involve some php selects.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="project">From Project</label>
        <select class="form-control"id="project"onchange="dropDrown(this.value)" name="project">
        <?php
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_project WHERE projectStatus = 1");
        $sql->execute();
        while($result=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $value        = $result['projectID'];
          $projectName  = $result['projectName'];
        echo"
        <option value='$value'> $projectName  </option>
        ";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <select class="form-control" id="village" name="village"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The AJAX:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function dropDown(id){
    var theID = id;
// assign your data to a varaible
var dataString= {theID:id};
$.ajax({
        url:    "includes/getVillage.php",
        type:   "POST",
        data:   dataString,
        cache:  false,
        success: function (data){
            $("#village").html(data);
        }
});
```

}

getVillage.php

```
<?php
include '../../connection';
$village = $_POST['theID'];
$sql                   =    "SELECT * FROM  tbl_village WHERE projectID = '$village'";
$query               =  $db->prepare($sql);
$results            =   $query->execute();
while($results=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $value = $results['villageID'];
  $text  = $results['villageName'];

  echo "<option value'$value'>$text</option>";
}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And exactly HOW is this code not working?

Comment: @MarcB How so? Anyway, it doesn't change the value on the second select tag which has an id of `#village`.

Comment: @JerlonBuenconsejo: You are already using `PDO`... Which is good. Do not use `$_POST[]`directly in the query string. Use [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: Try first checking `data` in your `success` function.  It probably will come up empty, because your `html` assignment looks ok.  Then see if there's something wrong with `dataString`.  Then check your query to make sure it's pulling the data.

Comment: read the site I linked to. and you're generating bad html anyways. `value'$value'`? That'd produce an unknown/illegal attribute - you're missing a `=`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not passing data through your ajax call.

```
function dropDown(id){
    var theID = id;
    // assign your data to a varaible
    var dataString= {theID:id};
    $.ajax({
            url:    "includes/getVillage.php",
            type:   "POST",
            data:   dataString,
            cache:  false,
            success: function (data){
                $("#village").html(data);
            }
    });
}
```

Alternatively you can pass the values in the below format

```
var  dataString= "theID="+id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I made a wrong connection. After evaluating the `getVillage.php` file alone. I received a lot of errors regarding my connection.php. Thanks guys.